# Oracle concat result

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

I have a table in below format:

Table Name: *employee*

| id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | e1 |
| 2 | e2 |

Need help in insert command:

```
INSERT INTO employee
  (id, code)
VALUES
  (SELECT max(id) + 1
     FROM employee,
          SELECT CONCAT('e', (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM employee)) FROM dual
   );
```

am getting an error on this, need help

Comment: That is nowhere close to valid SQL. `from employee from dual` won't produce anything but a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (ID, CODE)
(Select Nvl(Max(ID), 0) + 1 "NEW_ID", 'e' || To_Char(Nvl(Max(ID), 0) + 1) "NEW_CODE"
 From   EMPLOYEE)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SQL> select * from employee;

        ID CO
---------- --
         1 e1
         2 e2

SQL> insert into employee (id, code)
  2  with temp (max_id) as
  3    (select nvl(max(e.id), 0) + 1 from employee e)
  4  select t.max_id,
  5         'e' || t.max_id
  6  from temp t;

1 row created.

SQL> select * from employee;

        ID CO
---------- --
         1 e1
         2 e2
         3 e3

SQL>
```

---

**Although** it *works*, I'd suggest you **NOT** to do it this way. `MAX + 1` works in a single-user environment, but in a multi-user one it'll fail sooner or later because two (or more) users will fetch the same MAX value and try to insert a row, but only the first one who commits will succeed - others will

- get an error, if `ID` is unique (or primary key) (should be, I presume), or
- produce duplicates (if there's no uniqueness enforced)

What to do? Use a **sequence** instead.